# s3 mounted inside the container. how to expose it to the host?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, containers, mount, fuse

I have been playing around with possibility of having a container that mounts an s3 bucket and exposes it to the outside.

I used https://github.com/FindHotel/aws-s3-mount to have the s3 bucket mounted inside the container successfully. The mount is using FUSE.

I couldn't find a way to reach to that s3 mount from the host. Is it possible? Any other ideas to achieve the same goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do similar thing with glusterFS it requires higher permissions for the container but it's doable. In short docker command would be:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device fuse -v host_mount_dir:container_mount_dir:shared IMAGE COMMAND
```

If you get error like "Path /foo is mounted on /foo but it is not a shared mount ..." then your docker daemon runs in different mount namespace than systemd. There is an easy way to make it in same namespace:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/clear_mount_propagation_flags.conf
[Service]
MountFlags=shared
EOF
```

And restart docker daemon. TL;DR: mount will be visible on host if you mount it into dir binded by -v. Watch out for dragons ;)

Comment: This works with other mount types. The key is `:shared` flag on the volume (bind) when running container.