# Docker bind propagation mount error "is not a shared mount"

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume, snap, seafile-server

I am trying to mount a FUSE virtual filesystem from inside a Docker container and expose the mount point to the host.

Docker is installed via snap on Ubuntu 20.04

The software is a fresh install of [Seafile](http://seafile.com) (a Dropbox alternative), but this problem I believe is more related to Docker, snap, and mounting file systems on Ubuntu. For what it's worth, I was following the official instructions [here](https://manual.seafile.com/extension/fuse/#how-to-start-seaf-fuse-in-docker).

Inside the container (when it runs successfully), a script mounts a FUSE virtual filesystem to `/seafile-fuse` that makes the all files stored within Seafile visible.

**docker-compose.yml exerpt:**

```
version: '3.3'
services: 
  seafile:
    image: seafileltd/seafile-mc:latest
    container_name: seafile
    volumes:
      - /home/jonathan/seafile/seafile-data:/shared
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jonathan/seafile/seafile-fuse
        target: /seafile-fuse
        bind:
          propagation: rshared
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
```

This leads to:

```
ERROR: for seafile  Cannot start service seafile: path /home/jonathan/seafile/seafile-fuse is mounted on /home but it is not a shared mount
```

I found [this somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687025/s3-mounted-inside-the-container-how-to-expose-it-to-the-host/43687970#43687970) which hints that the issue may to do with the docker daemon running in a different namespace. But I am unable to get his solution to work.

**What do I need to do to connect the host directory `/home/jonathan/seafile/seafile-fuse` so that it sees the container directory `/seafile-fuse`?**

**Bonus question...**

Given that this is to be an internet facing home-server, is it necessary this this becomes a privileged container? Are there better options?

Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of mounting the filesystem from inside a theoretically-isolated container and trying to export it, why not run the mount directly on the host?  (I think for this use case, yes, it must be privileged.)